# how to update angular view only there is a change on database

Tags: php, angularjs, database, view, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to update my ng-repeat only when there is a change on the table I'm searching on my database. I'm currently doing this with $interval on angular every 700ms, as you can see:

```
var app = angular.module("games", []);

app.factory('app', ['$http', function($http, $interval) {

var obj={};
obj.getGames = function() { 
    return $http.get('ajax/gameread.php');
}
return obj;

}]);

app.controller("gamesCtrl", function($scope, $interval, app) {
    $interval(callInterval, 700);
    function callInterval(){
    app.getGames().then( function(data) {
    $scope.games = data.data;
    }); 
  }
});
```

And the the html:

```
 <div class="col-xs-8">
            <table ng-app="games" ng-controller="gamesCtrl" class="gametable">
            <tbody>
            <tr>

                <td id="box-title-games"><div class="left leftbox"><p class="sbold">Active Games</p></div> <a href="#"><div id="addgame" class="rightbox rightboxchar right"><p><i class=" fa fa-plus"></i> Add Game</p></a></div></td>
            </tr>
                <tr class="ops" ng-repeat="game in games">
                <td id="gamesli">{{game.game_p1}} {{game.gamebet}} <span class="last"><a href="gameplay/{{game.game_id}}" target="_blank" class="enter"><span class="letter-format-table">Enter</span></a></span></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>
        </div>
```

And the output from ajax/gameread.php is a json with each table info that I need.

But what this is doing, is updating my view every 700ms as you can see on my controller I'm using $interval. What I want to do is instead of using $interval use something that add a new `<TD>` on the ng-repeat if a new game was created or delete the `<TD>` if that content has changed, something like this:

if(new game on table games){ add a new td on the html with the info }

if(gamestatus changed on table games){ delete that TD from html }

Answer (score 0):

As long as you manipulate the games collection correctly the view will update accordingly.

Comment: Yes, it will but also if the collection is not manipulated it keeps updating the existing TD's, and thats annying cause its looks like they are blinking and you can not select their text because every 700ms (when it updates again) your selection will disappear